# (Blender Game Engine) Walk and Run cycle sound problems

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks, audio, collision

This has not bothered me for a while. But when working on the finishing touches of my game I seem to rather have it fixed than to keep it that way.*

**My problem is simple.** When I walk the 'Walk'sound comes up. But when I run the 'Walk'sound continues with the 'Run'sound. That way it seems like there is more than just one person to control.

**The workflow that I used to realize the sounds is easy.** I used a part of the ground as collision sensor and gave it a 'Collision' Sensor as well as 2 Different 'Keyboard' Sensors. One triggers the walkcycle sound actuator when pressing the 'W' key while the other needs the 'W'+'Shift' key to play the runcycle sound actuator.

*When trying to put the sounds on different logic bricks even connected to the Character it self, it did not seem to make any difference. That is why I came up with this very specific question.*

If there is anyone who can relate and or solve this mystery please let me know. Also if I have not provided enough info about my current situation reguarding this small sound issue then let me know as well as I am willing to explain the tiniest details if necessary.

***Thanks!,***

If some info is not clear; this is the actual Logic Brick for one of the floors I use in my game.

[image]

Comment: [BGE How to change a music loop in the middle of a game?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82907/2217) should help

Comment: I see how this would work but keep in mind that the walk and run cycle are triggered by a **Collision and Keyboard sensor** . So figuring this one out is a puzzle yet to be completed.  _Still I appreciate your input thanks David ;D_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Analyse

Your setup is not exclusive.

This means you can (and do) activate both actuators at the same time. This happens as both are listening to the same keyboard key <kbd>W</kbd>. The only difference is the key modifier <kbd>Left Shift</kbd>.

## Logical Condition - method

You need to exclude the key of the opposite operation when triggering the first operation.

You can do that with an additional keyboard sensor listening to <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> as well, but inverting the output [Invert].

This way the logic will be:

<kbd>W</kbd> + not <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> -> first actuator
<kbd>W</kbd> + <kbd>Left Shift</kbd> -> second actuator

Due to the exclusive conditions the actuators will run exclusive too.

## State - method

A better implementation is to use the build-in state machine. This way the operations are guarantied exclusive. You can even use the same key to toggle between walking and running.
Example:

State 1: waiting

State 2: walking

State 3: running

- waiting: when <kbd>W</kbd> -> walking
- walking: when not <kbd>W</kbd> -> waiting
- waiting: when <kbd>Shift</kbd> -> running
- walking: when not <kbd>W</kbd> -> waiting
- waiting: when not <kbd>Shift</kbd> -> walking